# Survival Curve - Probability of survival from time t(x) to t(y)

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am new to survival analysis and have what seems like an easy/dumb question.  I have fitted a survival curve in R from t(1) to t(36).  My understanding is the survival functiion is the probability of survival from time1 to time36(curve).  However, I am interested in survival from time(x) to time(36).  Is there a way to get this probability?

Comment: poisson ditribs? Just take the integral from t = x to t = 36? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8117/does-cox-regression-have-an-underlying-poisson-distribution/8118#8118

Comment: Thanks, but not sure what you mean.  Can you dumb it down for me.  Lets say i am looking at a vector of survival probabilities (t1=1, t2=.98,t3=.96,t4=.93,t5=.89).  Lets say, i want from t3 to t5 in this example.  How would i calculate this probability.  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The survival function tells you the probability of survival beyond the given time S(t) = P(T > t) where T is your (random) time of "death". That is why S(t1) = 1 since you are "alive" at the beginning of the observation period (so you are kind of "surviving" this moment already). Therefore your fitted function is *not* a probability of survival from t = t1 to t = t5. Rather, S(t5) tells you probability of survive beyond t_max (sorry if I misunderstood).

Since the survival function is an integral measure, it is easier to think about your process in terms of the time of death (the random variable T). So if you are interested in survival beyond time t3 (i.e. P(T > t3)) then it is just S(t3). It is of course less than 1 because you can die between time 0 and time t3.

On the other hand, if your question is "what is my probability to survive beyond t5 if I am not dead by t3?", they you are talking about conditional probability P(T > t5 | T > t3) so you want (new) S1(t3) to be 1. In that case you just need to re-scale your S(t5) by S(t3).